# Configuring FTP Client for Google Compute Website

Tags: wordpress, ftp, google-compute-engine

I know Google offers the Google Storage service to store website files, but I'm instead using Google Compute to host a virtual apache server on which I have my WordPress site installed.

I don't want to keep using the cryptic SSH terminal every time I want to make FTP transfers to my website, so I've chosen to evaluate Cyberduck and Filezilla as drag-and-drop alternatives. I'm having some trouble with the configuration however. Filezilla asks for: `Host`, `Username`, `Password`, and `Port` fields, while Cyberduck asks for `Server` and `Username` under the FTP/SFTP connection methods, or for `Project ID`/`Number` and `Authorization Code` under the Google Cloud Storage connection method (Keep in mind that I'm using Cloud *Compute*, not Cloud Storage). I can find the Project Number/ID, but where do you look for the rest of this information?

**Some Quick Information:**

-Project ID: `deep-pursuit-105021`

-External IP: `108.59.81.69`

---

**Cyberduck (*Google Cloud Storage* Method):**

[image]

**Cyberduck (*SFTP* Method):**

[image]

**FileZilla:**

[image]

**My Google SSH Terminal connected to the hosted Apache Server:**

[image]

Comment: Offtopic. You may be uploading code, but you're just USING those software packages, and we're not here to provide general software tech support.

Comment: I was forwarded here by Google's support team. Is there a better place for this question?

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer on [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).  These are all under the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the better option for FTP is WinSCP . I Use it and it is really convenient. You just have to configure it once , authorizing yourself with a compute engine ip,username and a private key file only . It is really great in term of session persistence also . If you need any help setting it up, let me know . However the steps are pretty easy , you just have to install WinSCP , create a private key using puttyGen and connect to your instance . You can find WinSCP connection details for Compute Engine here - https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_google_compute_engine

Comment: Just who do you think you are, giving all the right answers to the people who need them? I'll have you HIRED!

Comment: Haha !! Sure, glad it helped you :)

Comment: I keep getting an error when trying to add a folder to the themes directory on my remote server: "Permission denied.
Error code: 3
Error message from server: Permission denied". I tried `chmod 777 /var/www` in the Google SSH Terminal but it's still giving me this error.

Comment: That is a simple problem,  run sudo chmod 777 themes , from the directory the folder is present . Also by doing ls command , check if the color of themes folder changes, mostly green when permissions are applied . Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: How dare you? Do you think it's funny to make my life a living heaven? Do you?

Comment: Can't figure out whether you were able to solve it or not by your comment :) I guess it's working now .

Comment: Yeah, It worked the instant I tried it, thanks. I've been hung up on this all day!

Comment: Great !!!!  That's good to hear

Comment: Can you help me with another problem I'm having? I just changed some WordPress theme files and it's giving me an error:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165493/getting-error-establishing-a-database-connection-after-changing-wordpress-them